# Attempting to prove a sequence of real numbers always has a monotone subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, real-numbers

Below is my attempt at a proof of this proposition. Would love some feedback on how I possibly could improve it and whether my logic is airtight or not!

---

**Proposition**: If $(a_n)$ is a sequence of real numbers, then it has a monotone subsequence.

**Proof**:

I somehow want to account for boundedness vs unboundedness. So either there is a subsequence of $(a_n)$ with no least term, or each subsequence of $(a_n)$ has a least term.

What should we mean by a sequence having or not having a least term? I will define having a **least term** as:

> There exists an integer $n \geq 1$ such that for each integer $m \geq 1$ we have $a_n \leq a_m$.

In other words, there is one term that bounds the whole sequence from below.

The negation would then mean a sequence has no least term:

> For each integer $n \geq 1$ there exists an integer $ m \geq 1$ such that $a_n > a_m$.

**Remark**: This last definition of having no least term must imply that for each term there exists a smaller term **further along** in the sequence. Otherwise there would be some term $a_N$ after which there is not a single term smaller than $a_N$. But this would imply there is a least term for the whole sequence (just take the minimum of all terms from $a_1$ up to $a_N$).

*Case 1: A subsequence with no least term*

So, say now $(a_n)$ has a subsequence $(b_n)$ with no least term. Then for each integer $n \geq 1$ there exists an integer $m > n$ such that $b_n > b_m$.

Pick therefore any $n_1 \in \mathbb{N}$. Then there is $n_2 > n_1$ such that $b_{n_1} > b_{n_2}$. And for that $n_2$, there is another $n_3 > n_2$ such that $b_{n_1} > b_{n_2} > b_{n_3}$. Continuing in this fashion, we have our monotone subsequence (notice $x > y$ implies $x \geq y$, so it indeed is monotone).

*Case 2: Every subsequence has a least term*

If $(b_n)$ is a subsequence then it has a least term $b_{N_1}$. The trick is now to pick a subsequence of a subsequence!

Let $(b_{N_1 + n_k})$ be a subsequence of $(b_n)$. It is then also a subsequence of $(a_n)$ and thus has a least term $b_{N_2}$ where $N_2 > N_1$. But since it is a subsequence of $(b_n)$, we must have $b_{N_2} \geq b_{N_1}$.

We can next pick another subsequence of the subsequence $(b_{N_1 + n_k})$, namely $(b_{N_2 + n_k})$.
This will also have a least term and we will continue in the fashion intimated previously.

In this process we will yield a subsequence of terms $b_{N_1} \leq b_{N_2} \leq b_{N_3} \leq \ldots$ where $1 \leq N_1 < N_2 < N_3 < \ldots$ are integers. Hence we have our monotone subsequence.

Note: An analogous proof with greatest terms can be performed for the sequence $(-a_n)$.

Done. $\blacksquare$

---

Somewhat verbose and gratuitously exhaustive, but would love to hear your thoughts!

Comment: The condition $m\ne n$ is _not_ crucial: it is superfluous, because $a_n>a_m$ already implies that $m\ne n$.

Comment: @TonyK Oh yes indeed, how did I not think of that. Thank you!

Comment: Note that under "Related" there are several older questions on this fact about sequences. Maybe you'll find some of them ehlpful.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Yes absolutely thank you, I've been meaning to look further into others proofs. But before that, my main aim here was to see if I could write up a proof of my own and hopefully get some feedback on it.

Comment: Isn't your question equivalent to proving  : $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}a_{n}=\alpha\iff\lim_{k\to+\infty}a_{n_{k}}=\alpha? $$